# Animate background color's saturation or lightness using JQuery

Tags: jquery, colors, background, jquery-animate, hsl

I did a search, and I found a function that randomly changes RGB values only, namely
http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/

However, I simply want to change a header color's HSL value (either saturation or lightness).  I want the color's saturation or lightness to change very slowly and subtly.

Any hints or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.